# Installing the Tomcat7 examples webapp on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, webapps, tomcat7

I used the `sudo apt-get install tomcat7-examples`.

They were installed in `/usr/share/tomcat7-examples/examples` directory.

Tomcat could not locate them from the URL :

```
127.0.0.1:8080/examples/    
HTTP Status 404 - /examples/
```

I attempted to copy them to the webapps directory but that failed.

```
$ sudo cp /usr/share/tomcat7-examples/examples/*  /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/examples/.

cp: omitting directory 'jsp'    
cp: omitting directory 'servlets'  
cp: omitting directory 'WEB-INF'
```

What am I missing?

Havingsame problem with docs, common, and admin.

Answer (score 0):

Use cp -r to copy over directories.  Also make sure target directories exist

Comment: In it's current state, the answer is not very useful. Would you elaborate the answer to include more details like an example?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't copy anything.**

After you have started your copy command, you should now remove the folder `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/examples` via

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/examples
```

---

**The correct way**

After installing the package `tomcat7-examples` restart your tomcat7

```
sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

After that open the URL http://localhost:8080/examples/ and you will see this

[image]